# SQL Anywhere doesn't work on VPS

Tags: linux, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to connect to SQL Anywhere database on external server. I'm working on VPS Linux.

Following [documentation](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1100/en/dbprogramming_en11/php-s-4388017.html) when I run command `./bin32/sa_config.sh` I get this error.

```
-bash: ./bin32/sa_config.sh: Permission denied
```

Permission are: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1201 Sep 10 14:50 sa_config.sh`.
The same is when I run config from `bin64`.

In `phpinfo()` I have error:

```
SQLAnywhere client version  The SQLAnywhere client libraries could not be loaded. Please ensure that libdbcapi_r.so can be found in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
```

I added this line to `/etc/init.d/httpd`:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/sql_anywhere/
```

And to this location I copied `libdbcapi_r.so` and `libdblib12_r.so`. I tried those files from `lib32` and `lib64`.

I add location to `php-5.x.y_sqlanywhere_r.so` in `php.ini` and line to run it automatically.

How to make SQL Anywhere working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the sa_config.sh file like this:

```
. <path>sa_config.sh
```

Note the space between the `.` and the filename. That will allow the script to change environment variables in the current shell.